# how to get rid of this repetition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

how make that more beatiful?

```
Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(_leftBorder, _topBorder), new Vector2(_rightBorder, _topBorder));
Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(_leftBorder, _topBorder), new Vector2(_leftBorder, _bottomBorder));
Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(_rightBorder, _bottomBorder), new Vector2(_leftBorder, _bottomBorder));
Gizmos.DrawLine(new Vector2(_rightBorder, _bottomBorder), new Vector2(_rightBorder, _topBorder));
```

Comment: Start by formatting it, secondly maybe you can add splash of colour, and a diffrent font maybe? If you have a concrete question add concrete constraints

Comment: i am  making not a cube. It is rectangle

Comment: it's just a drawn rectangle on the stage. there is nothing but this

Comment: You are drawing a rectangle .. you could as well simply use [`Gizmos.DrawWireCube`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawWireCube.html)

Comment: sometimes you just have to type the code, getting fancy will only confuse you and others later

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could store the vectors in fields and use a meaningful method name:

```
private Vector2 _topLeft = new Vector2(_leftBorder, _topBorder);
private Vector2 _topRight = new Vector2(_rightBorder, _topBorder);
private Vector2 _bottomLeft = new Vector2(_leftBorder, _bottomBorder);
private Vector2 _bottomRight = new Vector2(_rightBorder, _bottomBorder);

private void DrawRectangle()
{
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_topLeft, _topRight);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_topLeft, _bottomLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_bottomRight, _bottomLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_bottomRight, _topRight);
}
```

This is at least much more readable and also more reusable.

Comment: and you can make the line drawing itself in fewer lines?

Comment: this is a repetition, I just think that such repetitions can somehow be made more beautiful, shorter

Comment: What if the positions need to be updated continuously anyway?

Answer (score 0):

**First things first:** I find [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275803/how-to-get-rid-of-this-repetition#answer-71276002) to be the absolutely clearest, most intuitive and reusable implementation for your use case. If I were to implement it myself, I would have followed Tim's suggestions.

---

Seeing as less repetition seems to be of importance to you, I'll provide a possible implementation where you first create two `List<Vector2>` (one for the "left-hand vectors" and one for the "right-hand vectors" in your code example), then use a double [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-6.0) to make all the needed calls to `Gizmos.DrawLine( )`:

```csharp
var baseVectors = new List<Vector2>
{ 
    new Vector2(_leftBorder, _topBorder),
    new Vector2(_rightBorder, _bottomBorder)
};

var orthogonalVectors = new List<Vector2>
{
    new Vector2(_rightBorder, _topBorder),
    new Vector2(_leftBorder, _bottomBorder)
};

baseVectors
    .ForEach(baseVector => orthogonalVectors
        .ForEach(orthVector => Gizmos.DrawLine(baseVector, orthVector)));
```

If you decide to implement this, I would strongly advise you to find more descriptive/correct names for your lists. I couldn't come up with any better suggestions (especially as it seems to me that `Vector2` is rather a point than a vector).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code like this, don't know if it can be made more beautiful

```
public Vector2 _topLeft;
public Vector2 _topRight;
public Vector2 _bottomLeft;
public Vector2 _bottomRight;

void Awake()
{
    _topLeft = new Vector2(_leftBorder, _topBorder);
    _topRight = new Vector2(_rightBorder, _topBorder);
    _bottomLeft = new Vector2(_leftBorder, _bottomBorder);
    _bottomRight = new Vector2(_rightBorder, _bottomBorder);
}

public void DrawRectangle()
{
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_topLeft, _topRight);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_topLeft, _bottomLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_bottomRight, _bottomLeft);
    Gizmos.DrawLine(_bottomRight, _topRight);
}
```